# Using QProcess in PyQt for Running a Class Method

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5, qprocess

I'm trying to use `QProcess` to run a class method in a separate process. I know that the following code won't work but I am wondering if there is a tweak for starting a new process by `QProcess` rather than using `multiprocessing.process(target=function_name)`

```
import multiprocessing
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20

    def loop(self,):
        for i in range(1,1000):
            self.x = i

M = MyClass()

# p = multiprocessing.process(target=MyClass.loop) # Is QProcess capable of doing this?
p = QtCore.QProcess(myClass.loop) # I know this won't work but I am looking for a way to use QProcess for ths purpose
p.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to open a QThread and put all your variables into the thread class, in the thread class do the QProcess, and here is an example from my project:
https://www.github.com/min20120907/Cell_RCNN_Qt/tree/master/Cell_Trainer.py